# A package of errors (overfull hbox, float too large and drives not supported)

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, overleaf

I would like to draw a graphic in latexdraw, but the following errors occur:

- Overfull \hbox (992.05664pt too wide) in paragraph
- Float too large for page by 2929.13472pt
- Your graphic driver pgfsys-dvips.def does not support fadings. This warning is given only once

My code is:

```
\documentclass[10pt, reqno]{amsart}


\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm, epsfig}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}
\usepackage{tkz-base}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}
\usepackage{esint}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}


%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\usepackage{stackrel}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{pstricks}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{pst-grad} % For gradients
\usepackage{pst-plot} % For axes
\usepackage[space]{grffile} % For spaces in paths
\usepackage{etoolbox} % For spaces in paths
\usepackage{geometry}



\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{cond}{Condition A}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\date{}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\numberwithin{theorem}{section}
\numberwithin{lemma}{section}
\numberwithin{corollary}{section}
\numberwithin{remark}{section}
\numberwithin{proposition}{section}
\numberwithin{definition}{section}



\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
    \psscalebox{1.0 1.0} % Change this value to rescale the drawing.
    {
        \begin{pspicture}(0,-63.29843)(49.745453,59.206844)
            \rput(0.029999102,-63.268425){\psaxes[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04, tickstyle=full, axesstyle=axes, labels=none, ticks=none, ticksize=0.1411111cm, dx=1.0cm, dy=1.0cm](0,0)(0,0)(10,10)}
            \psbezier[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04](38.396713,58.491898)(38.67653,49.891182)(37.634064,50.391304)(46.050304,50.24492797069684)
            \psbezier[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04](39.72858,58.402637)(39.62377,50.989346)(39.24665,52.01489)(46.12858,51.90263671875)
            \psbezier[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04](41.275246,58.202637)(41.010544,53.067715)(42.62985,53.536205)(46.035244,53.56263671875)
            \rput[bl](45.55858,53.952637){$f$}
            \rput[bl](45.37858,52.272636){$g$}
            \rput[bl](45.338577,50.612637){$g$}
            \rput[bl](47.439754,49.06288){q}
            \psrotate(37.140995, 59.015865){0.626584}{\rput[bl](37.140995,59.015865){r}}
            \rput(36.845245,49.126625){\psrotate(5.0, 5.0){0.626584}{\psaxes[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04, tickstyle=full, axesstyle=axes, labels=none, ticks=none, ticksize=0.1252cm, dx=1.0cm, dy=1.0cm](0,0)(0,0)(10,10)}}
            \pscustom[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04, linestyle=dotted, dotsep=0.10583334cm]
            {
                \newpath
                \moveto(36.89858,50.10264)
                \lineto(37.588753,50.101154)
                \curveto(37.933838,50.100414)(38.33644,50.098934)(38.393955,50.09819)
                \curveto(38.45147,50.09745)(38.911583,50.09671)(39.314186,50.09671)
                \curveto(39.716785,50.09671)(40.176903,50.09597)(40.234417,50.09523)
                \curveto(40.29193,50.09449)(41.11151,50.093006)(41.87358,50.092266)
                \curveto(42.635647,50.091526)(43.440845,50.090042)(43.483982,50.089306)
                \curveto(43.52712,50.088562)(43.958477,50.087082)(44.3467,50.08634)
                \curveto(44.734924,50.085598)(45.166283,50.084118)(45.209415,50.083378)
                \curveto(45.252552,50.082638)(45.36758,50.081154)(45.439476,50.080414)
                \curveto(45.511368,50.079674)(45.89959,50.078194)(46.21592,50.07745)
            }
            \pscustom[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04, linestyle=dotted, dotsep=0.10583334cm]
            {
                \newpath
                \moveto(37.065247,53.369305)
                \lineto(37.75542,53.36745)
                \curveto(38.100506,53.366528)(38.503105,53.364674)(38.560623,53.363747)
                \curveto(38.618137,53.362823)(39.07825,53.361897)(39.480854,53.361897)
                \curveto(39.883453,53.361897)(40.34357,53.36097)(40.401085,53.360043)
                \curveto(40.4586,53.35912)(41.27818,53.357265)(42.040245,53.35634)
                \curveto(42.80231,53.355415)(43.607513,53.35356)(43.65065,53.35264)
                \curveto(43.693787,53.35171)(44.125145,53.349857)(44.513367,53.348934)
                \curveto(44.90159,53.348007)(45.332947,53.346157)(45.376083,53.34523)
                \curveto(45.41922,53.344303)(45.53425,53.342453)(45.606144,53.341526)
                \curveto(45.678036,53.3406)(46.066257,53.33875)(46.382587,53.337822)
            }
            \pscustom[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04, linestyle=dotted, dotsep=0.10583334cm]
            {
                \newpath
                \moveto(36.98858,51.702637)
                \lineto(37.658638,51.700787)
                \curveto(37.993668,51.69986)(38.384533,51.698006)(38.440372,51.697083)
                \curveto(38.49621,51.696156)(38.942913,51.69523)(39.333782,51.69523)
                \curveto(39.724648,51.69523)(40.171352,51.694305)(40.227192,51.69338)
                \curveto(40.28303,51.69245)(41.078724,51.6906)(41.81858,51.689674)
                \curveto(42.558434,51.688747)(43.340168,51.686897)(43.382046,51.68597)
                \curveto(43.423927,51.685043)(43.842712,51.683193)(44.21962,51.682266)
                \curveto(44.596527,51.68134)(45.015312,51.67949)(45.057194,51.678562)
                \curveto(45.09907,51.677635)(45.210747,51.675785)(45.280544,51.67486)
                \curveto(45.35034,51.673935)(45.72725,51.67208)(46.03436,51.671154)
            }
            \pscustom[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04, linestyle=dotted, dotsep=0.10583334cm]
            {
                \newpath
                \moveto(38.300663,58.452637)
                \lineto(38.300663,56.223614)
                \curveto(38.300663,55.1091)(38.29754,53.458363)(38.29441,52.922134)
                \curveto(38.291286,52.385906)(38.288162,51.670937)(38.288162,51.492195)
                \curveto(38.288162,51.31345)(38.291286,51.01905)(38.29441,50.903397)
                \curveto(38.29754,50.78774)(38.303787,50.535397)(38.30691,50.398712)
                \curveto(38.310036,50.262024)(38.316288,50.00968)(38.319412,49.894028)
                \curveto(38.322536,49.77837)(38.32566,49.568085)(38.32566,49.473454)
                \curveto(38.32566,49.378826)(38.3241,49.24214)(38.319412,49.11597)
            }
            \pscustom[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04, linestyle=dotted, dotsep=0.10583334cm]
            {
                \newpath
                \moveto(39.586357,58.3193)
                \lineto(39.574135,56.71541)
                \curveto(39.568024,55.91346)(39.568024,54.852818)(39.574135,54.594124)
                \curveto(39.580246,54.33543)(39.586357,51.541546)(39.586357,49.006355)
            }
            \pscustom[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04, linestyle=dotted, dotsep=0.10583334cm]
            {
                \newpath
                \moveto(41.12358,58.119305)
                \lineto(41.131912,57.633053)
                \curveto(41.136078,57.389927)(41.144413,57.03537)(41.14858,56.92394)
                \curveto(41.152744,56.812508)(41.152744,56.214825)(41.14858,55.728573)
                \curveto(41.144413,55.242325)(41.144413,54.07735)(41.14858,53.39863)
                \curveto(41.152744,52.719902)(41.156914,51.484016)(41.156914,50.926857)
                \curveto(41.156914,50.369694)(41.152744,49.761883)(41.14858,49.71123)
                \curveto(41.144413,49.66058)(41.136078,49.56941)(41.131912,49.528885)
                \curveto(41.127747,49.488365)(41.121494,49.346542)(41.115246,49.042637)
            }
            \rput[bl](36.331913,49.8193){1}
            \rput[bl](36.23191,51.38597){2}
            \rput[bl](34.865246,52.98597){$d$}
            \rput[bl](37.765247,48.452637){$c$}
            \rput[bl](39.43191,48.419304){$b$}
            \rput[bl](40.79858,48.35264){$a$}
        \end{pspicture}
    }
\end{figure}




\end{document}
```

Any suggestions for solve this mistake?

Thanks

Comment: unrelated but no document written after 1993 should use `epsfig` and you specify it three times!!!  Also you have commented out `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and replaced it by `latin1` but that is dangerous, for example _all_ examples posted to this site are in UTF-8 (the site translates any files uploaded as latin 1) so that decalaration would force latex to give errors on any non-ascii characters.

Comment: also do not load `grffile` (it does nothing at all in current releases)

Comment: your picture is too big for a page and contains the comment `\psscalebox{1.0 1.0} % Change this value to rescale the drawing.` have you tried changing those numbers to something smaller?

Comment: Further to the comments from @DavidCarlisle, you should probably load `hyperref` last, and also remove all instances of packages loaded more than once.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes, but the figure appears on the right side of the leaf almost out of sight.

Comment: if you set it to a scale of 1.5, 1.5 (the largest you can do without warning) [it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aolna.png) which is not all on the right. Perhaps you don't want the two lines that are at the bottom left of the page in which case go back to your original drawing and remove them, then the bit at the top right will naturally rescale to the page.